# React.js inputs not binding to value

Tags: reactjs

In my react.js application, I have the following dialog:

```html
                <Dialog  open={this.state.dialogIsOpen} onClose = {this.closeDialog} >
                    <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Create New Test User</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>

                        <Grid container>
                            <Grid item xs = "6">
                                <label htmlFor = "id">Id: </label>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs = "6">
                                <input id = "id" value = {this.state.id}></input>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item xs = "6">
                                <label htmlFor = "name">Name: </label>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs = "6">
                                <input id = "name" value = {this.state.name}></input>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item xs = "6">
                                <label htmlFor = "email">Email:</label>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs = "6">
                                <input id = "email" value = {this.state.email}></input>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <button onClick = {this.createUser}>OK</button>
                    </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
```

The button at the bottom calls the following function:

```html
    createUser()
    {
        alert(this.state.email);
        alert(this.state.users.length);
        var newUser = {
            id: this.state.id,
            name: this.state.name,
            emailAddress: this.state.email
        }
        this.state.users.push(newUser);
        this.closeDialog();
    }
```

When the createUser function is called, this.state.email, name, and id are undefined. However, this.state.users is the array that I expect it to be.  It appears that the inputs are not binding correctly to the state values. Is there something special I need to do to bind inputs within a dialog?

Comment: Can you show us how you defined state?

Comment: constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            users: [],
            editId: null,
            dialogIsOpen: false
        };

        this.exitEdit = this.exitEdit.bind(this);
        this.openDialog = this.openDialog.bind(this);
        this.closeDialog = this.closeDialog.bind(this);
        this.createUser = this.createUser.bind(this);
    }

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mutate state variables other than using `setState`

try this instead:

```
this.setState({
  users: [...users, newUser]
})
```

instead of calling `this.state.users.push(newUser)`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

1. I had to create an onChange handler for each input to send data changes back into the model when the user typed in the inputs. I found that [here](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/how-to-work-with-forms-inputs-and-events-in-react-c337171b923b)
2. I had to make the onchange handler generic as documented [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/react-quick-tip-easy-data-binding-with-a-generic-onchange-handler-fb0254a7094e)